SOL nested address from Tangem to Zelcore
Zelcore team said:
This issue is created by the Tangem wallet treating my Flux-SOL address similarly to a Solana public key, resulting in the transfer being sent to a newly generated address rather than my existing Flux-SOL Associated Token Account (ATA) address.
I sent flux-sol to my zelcore wallet (Solana public key AM1aJzkKVfi8SvxCahTPrfthxzbX77rVJcPD5WtrctUD)
H8ZeyddTsgDcRLgScWDc8Dkmtdz1zaqLooAAbAsXFQ7d, which in turn owns the address holding my Flux-SOL balance (DtVhcS46BACjt93JfkkgoBLubnfosv9gkqaH4xHBYHxr), it confirms that my private key does indeed control these addresses.
Zelcore are unable to provide a private key for DtVhcS46BACjt93JfkkgoBLubnfosv9gkqaH4xHBYHxr as it was not an address created by the Zelcore wallet. To access my Flux-SOL balance, i will need some assistance from the Solana development team, who can guide you through accessing or transferring the balance from this nested address.
Thanks for your support
